# dynamic PHP links rewritten with mod_rewrite ..changing from commas to slashes

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I have a PHP script that "generates" static PHP links from dynamic PHP links if mod_rewrite is enabled. It uses the same piece of code throughout the page to generate the links, which is:

```
if ($var_array)
            {
                    while(list($key, $value) = each($var_array))
                    {
                            $sanitized_value = sanitize_var($value);
                            $output .= $sanitized_value.','.$key.',';
                    }
            }
            $output .= $base_url;
```

The .htaccess has the following mod_rewrite code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*)$ $2.php?rewrite_params=$1&page_url=$2
```

As you can see, the links are currently separated by a coma ( , ) and a dynamic URL like:

```
http://www.url.com/page.php?category=dogs&parent_id=1050
```

then becomes:

```
http://www.url.com/dogs,category,1050,parent_id,page
```

Unfortunately there are 2 problems with this.

1. I read that links with comas are not appropriate.
2. The entire URL is currently in "reverse".

**I'd rather have it like: http://www.url.com/page/category/dogs/parent_id/1050**

Now, I tried to change the PHP part from

```
$output .= $sanitized_value.','.$key.',';
```

to

```
$output .= $sanitized_value.'/'.$key.'/';
```

And then the .htaccess from

```
RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*)$ $2.php?rewrite_params=$1&page_url=$2
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $2.php?rewrite_params=$1&page_url=$2
```

in an attempt to replace ( , ) with ( / ) but that doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting 404 for URL `http://www.url.com/page/category/dogs/parent_id/1050`

Comment: Yes, when replacing the , with the / in the above mentioned places (twice in the PHP and once in the .htaccess), I get 404 links not found ...

Comment: PHP will come later, lets stick to rewrite first. Are you getting 404 for `http://www.url.com/page/category/dogs/parent_id/1050`? Where does `page.php` exist?

Comment: Your rewrite rule `^(.*)/(.*)$` is only going to catch two items, so your example URL will not parse properly. You need to show more code, for example where is `$var_array` coming from? I'd suggest you remove the stuff about commas, it's complicating the question more than it needs to be.